# display Yes as a checkbox from database

Tags: c#, winforms

i am a newbie for C#.i have a column called '[Add Additional Part?]' in sqltable with value 'YES' or ''. how can i show the yes as a checkbox=checked in C# winforms?

Comment: What code are you using so far? Are you using an ORM? For boolean data you're typically better off using a `bit` field for purposes of speed and data integrity.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do something like this:

```
protected void someFunction()
{
    DataTable dt = getDataFromDataBase();
    CheckBox cb = null;
    for(int r=0;r<dt.Rows.Count;r++)
    {
        cb = new CheckBox();
        cb.Checked = mDbValueToBool((String)dt.Rows[r]["Add Additional Part"]));
        mForm.Controls.Add(cb);
    }
}
protected Boolean mDbValueToBool(String boolValue)
{
    if(boolValue.Equals("YES"))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```